# Is there a way to create X number of buttons without me having to write each and one of them?

Tags: c#, xaml

So i'm trying to create a store using WPF and I've come to the point where I need to start adding the products, but I can't add each and every product to a button by myself, so I'm wondering is there a way to add an X amount of buttons without me having to code each and everyone of them individually

This is part of my School's end of the year project. I'm using WPF and SQL to host a database server.

I expect for example everytime the application refreshes it adds a button if there's a product for it.

Comment: Use an `ItemsControl` with a button in its `ItemTemplate`. When you properly bind your list of products to it, buttons will be created for you "automagically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should obtain the number of products from the server.

For each product, create a new button and assign its name accordingly.

You should be able to make a dummy button to duplicate over and over again for each product.